# How to update datepicker Year to Buddhist era

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Tried to change year Buddhist era +543 from datepicker framework but it's notworked.

I used this framework code this link http://keith-wood.name/datepick.HTML
I reading document date function and tried to this code but notworked again :(

```
$('.picker').change(periods); 

function periods() { 
    var date = new Date($('.picker').datepick('getDate')[0].getTime()); 
    $.datepick.add(date, parseInt(543), 'y'); 
    $('.picker').val($.datepick.formatDate(date)); 
}
```

How to Year +543 Pls help me

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting an error because, The year you set by adding 543 years for the current date is not available in the calender.
please post your full code in order to check.
First of all try with changing calendar mode to Thai.

Because Thai calendar is same as buddhist calendar
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thai_solar_calendar

Note: This Thai calendar option is not available in the datepicker so you need to use calendar control.

http://keith-wood.name/calendars.html

Here is the sample

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>jQuery Calendars Datepicker</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.calendars.picker.css">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.plugin.js"></script>
<!--<script src="jquery.calendars.all.js"></script><!-- Use instead of calendars, plus, and picker below -->
<script src="jquery.calendars.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.calendars.plus.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.calendars.picker.js"></script>
<!--<script src="jquery.calendars.picker.ext.js"></script><!-- Include for ThemeRoller styling -->
<script src="jquery.calendars.thai.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
//  $.calendars.picker.setDefaults({renderer: $.calendars.picker.themeRollerRenderer}); // Requires jquery.calendars.picker.ext.js
    var calendar = $.calendars.instance('thai');
    $('#inlineDatepicker').calendarsPicker({calendar: calendar, onSelect: showDate});
});

function showDate(date) {
    alert('The date chosen is ' + date);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="inlineDatepicker"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: calendarpicker not use with my website becuase I used jquery version 2.0.2 but calendarpicker used 1.11 but datepicker can used jquery 2.0.2

Comment: How about using Thai calendar in keith-wood datepicker?

Comment: I downloaded both keith-wood datepicker and calendar picker. both of them are using jQuery 1.11